# BB 10 WebWorks signing Doubts

Tags: blackberry-webworks, blackberry-10

I have a doubt regarding signing and packaging in BB 10 WebWorks.

Is the signing key similar to normal smartphone signing keys or is it different for a playbook?

If so, where will be the signing keys installed in the folder.

I am getting signing issues.

```
D:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK 1.0.0.7>bbwp E:\A
```

ppBB10\HelloWorldBB10.zip -s E:\PackBB10 -g Pass123# -o E:\OutputBB10

D:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK 1.0.0.7>"D:\Progr
am Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK 1.0.0.7\dependencies\node
\node.exe" "D:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK 1.0.0
.7\lib\bbwp.js" E:\AppBB10\HelloWorldBB10.zip -s E:\PackBB10 -g Pass123# -o E:\O
utputBB10
[INFO]    Populating application source
[INFO]    Parsing config.xml
[ERROR]   Cannot sign application - failed to find signing keys

D:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK 1.0.0.7>

Can anyone help me on this

Regards
Rakesh Shankar.P

Comment: BB10 is QNX based. So signing process should be same as for PlayBook.

Comment: I found out the place where signing keys are installed,but while packing and signing thr command prompt ,I am getting error as Cannot sign application - failed to find signing keys

Comment: Could you show what command line do you use for signing?

Comment: i updated the error in the question itelf,thanks

Comment: You are using some IDE. sorry I was thinking that you're using command line tool. Here is post where guy describes how to sign app over command line tools: http://inflagrantedelicto.memoryspiral.com/2011/02/blackberry-playbook-code-signing-process/

Comment: Issue was solved when i updated with latest beta SDK release of BB 10 Web Works(1.0.0.15).and this is not IDE,I am doing it in command tool only

Answer (score 0):

Issue was solved when i updated with latest beta SDK release of BB 10 Web Works(1.0.0.15).